# Synchronous communication with gazebo

Tags: control, gazebo, rosservice, robot, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to implement a robot controller using ros + gazebo - So, what I want it to tell gazebo a particular command and then gazebo should return the state after 1 second. And after that it should pause itself.Now, I do some processing and again give a command - and it should again run for only 1 second.

I need my actions to be used for equal amounts of time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211795/synchronous-communication-with-gazebo/) by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22426/abdealijk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2015-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get that level of control of gazebo's flow you will need to write a plugin for gazebo. I suggest you ask for help on http://answers.gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since a google search with the 3 words, gazebo, pause and ros leads to here. I will just drop the few lines needed to pause/unpause gazebo in command/cpp and python ( it took me 3 hours to do it in cpp and despite it being a little out of the scope of the question, it may save this time to a few people). Note that at the end I propose a solution to solve this particular problem without the need to create a plugin.

To (un)pause in command line :

```
rosservice call gazebo/(un)pause_physics
```

Those who know how to use services should already know the following but for those who never used services before ( like me ) :

in cpp :

```
#include <std_srvs/Empty.h>

ros::ServiceClient pauseGazebo = nh.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/gazebo/(un)pause_physics");
std_srvs::Empty emptySrv;
pauseGazebo.call(emptySrv);
```

in Python ( available [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/59049/how-to-call-pause_physics-service/) )

```
from std_srvs.srv import Empty
(un)pause = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/(un)pause_physics', Empty)
```

That's for pausing and upausing gazebo.

For this particular problem :

[The gazebo ros communication](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_comm)  include as services

- get_model_state,
- apply_body_wrench, apply_joint_effort,  /gazebo/set_model_state
  and there is also the parameter /use_sim_time

With that it should be possible to do what was asked without writing a plugin. I must say that even if it's possible, I'm not sure if it's advised to process like this instead of creating a plugin for complex interactions with gazebo.

Edit :
Indeed @gvdhoorn, It allows to stop the simulation during the processing time of any message ( which is what i thought the OP wanted before your comment) but to do the opposite ( which is having a simulation running but no processing ) is indeed not as straight forward with those services.

I belive it's possible to do what's requested but that it may be very unpractical to do :
A  "time_managment" node which would subscribe at the command and publish a boolean ROS_FREEZE read by all the other nodes should do the job no ?

- In the node where the command is published, when the command is published, send at the same time a gazebo "unpause". In the "time_managment" node, receiving the command should trigger the publication of a ROS_FREEZE = TRUE.
- All the other nodes running should subscribe on this topic and either enter a loop waiting for another message on this particular topic or individually changing the way all the other callbacks work when ROS_FREEZE = true
  -after 1s,the time_namagment node should send a ROS_FREEZE=false allowing one processing step and the same time a call to the rosservice to "pause" gazebo.
- then on the next issued command, the cycle can restart.

This should work no ?

---

Originally posted by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) with karma: 267 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-02**:
It's good to draw attention to the services that Gazebo exposes for controlling the simulation, but those cannot be considered a proper solution to what the OP is asking for here: a way to implement a lock-step execution pattern between all involved nodes & Gazebo.

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-06-07**:
indeed, I answered in my edit, what do you think about it ?